# Entity Framework Stored Procedure Object Type into a Standard object type

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, object, stored-procedures

Entity Framework creates an object for each of your tables and stored procedures.

How could I change a stored procedure type into a table type object?

Example: I have a table object `Customers` and I have a stored procedure object `spSearchCustomers`

```
Dim results As IEnumerable(Of spSearchCustomers) = dbContext.spSearchCustomers(FName, LName, Active)
Return results.ToList()
```

This returns a list of `spSearchCustomers`, but I need a list of `Customers`.

It is the same data same table the `spSearchCustomers` just searches the `Customer` table for unique records and brings them back as a `spSearchCustomers` instead of a `Customer` object.

How could I convert it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using database first approch, in that case you can go to your model `.edmx` file -> `open Wizard` -> click on `Stored Procedures` -> Click on `Add Function Import` -> then select the type from the list of entities that it should return (in your case `Customer`).

**WARNING** If you are planning of regenerating model quite often, keep in mind that you will have to do this for every Stored Procedure every time you regenerate it.

Comment: Thank you.  That could be a real hassle in developing to do this for ever Sproc ever time you regenerate the model.  In this application the database already exists so what would you do in that case with using the entity framework?